# Customising Graph in android

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

Hi I am using achartengine for designing graph in Android 
I want to space out the Y axis values as seen in the image .
How can I achieve it .

[image: Graph from Achart Engine]

I have use the following values to design the graph

**Series 1 :**

```
   int x[] = {5, 10, 15, 20, 30 , 35, 45};
   int y[] = {50, 100, 300, 200, 250 , 250 , 300};
```

and

**Series 2 :**

```
    int x1[]={10,20,30,40,50,60,70};
    int y1[]={50, 100, 300, 200, 250 , 250 , 300};
```

To add the series I am using the following code

```
XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
            dataset.addSeries(series);
            dataset.addSeries(series1);
```

To add the renderer file I am using the following code

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
            XYSeriesRenderer renderer1 = new XYSeriesRenderer();





  mRenderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.CENTER);

        mRenderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
```

Then this series is added into the mRenderer  and the Graphical View is set up

```
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
            mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer1);

            GraphicalView view = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mRenderer);
```

Comment: what package are you using? please add a link to it, or show more of your code.

Comment: please check the code .. Do you need more of it

Comment: I need to space out the Yaxis and the values of 100 , 200 , 300 as seen in the image

Comment: Need to look at the package youre using.

Comment: Did not get you ... I am using achartengine for drawing graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this:

```
mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this library https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/ it might help you

Comment: I have already referred to this site . But it does not show from where I can space out the values and the Y axis